# Comparing git changes between two files programmatically in .Net

Tags: .net, git, libgit2sharp

I have the libgit2sharp library currently extracting information around two commits, before and after changes.

Looking at the functionality available within the dll.

```
var patch = repo.Diff.Compare<Patch>(oldTree, newTree);
```

This exposes lines added and removed as counts and a patch containing the differing text.I was hoping to get something that doesn't need pre-processing. Obviously, the patch looks like:

```
++ Added stuff
-- Removed stuff
```

Which isn't particularly useful. Has anyone else come across this issue or is aware of another approach?

Much appreciated.